# Understanding the train_test_split method

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, training-data

I am working my way through the Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit learn textbook and on chapter2, the author suggests to stratify one of the features (income group) during the train_test_split using the following code:

```
strat_train_set, strat_test_set = train_test_split(housing, 
test_size=0.2,random_state=42,stratify=housing["income_cat"])
```

From my understanding, it is important that all attributes(including the target) are equally represented in the train and test dataset.

In the following code above, we cannot guarantee that other attributes are split as per the ratios in their respective columns. Shouldn't all the attributes be stratified splits?

Is that correct? Or am I misunderstanding the code

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to read this question as it answers Your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250273/benefits-of-stratified-vs-random-sampling-for-generating-training-data-in-classi

Comment: What would the "ratio" be for a column with a continuous datatype like float?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question!

As I understand you have 20% of your data as test data.

This is important because when we are training the model we would be able to make sure that the proportion of values in the sample produced will be the same as the proportion of values provided to parameter stratify.

For example, if variable `income_cat` is a categorical variable with values `High` and `Low` and there are 25% of `High` and 75% of `Low`, stratify=`housing["income_cat"]` will make sure that your random split has 25% of `High` and 75% of `Low`s.

Hope it helps!